# Caching a list of Django comments

Tags: django, django-comments

I have [a site](http://www.pepysdiary.com/) which uses the standard Django comments (well, a subclass of that, but mostly the same). I want to cache the list of comments that's rendered on each page, as that's quite a big and slow query. But, while I know how to cache individual querysets, I can't see how best to do it for the comments app.

It looks like the querysets for these lists of comments [are generated in the `BaseCommentNode` templatetag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/contrib/comments/templatetags/comments.py#L71). So I can't see an easy way to see if there's a cached version of that QS and return that if so... what's my best way of nicely caching this query?

(I'm also caching every page for all logged-out users, with a 5 minute expiry, but *think* my site would benefit from caching queries like this for a longer period.)